# Unity 2D multiplayer server sync question

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Hy, I have a pretty simple multiplayer 2D shooting game and I have a little problem. I am able to flip my character locally, but I don't know how to do it on all clients. Can you help me?

My functions look like this at the moment

```
public void OnChangeFlip(int FlipPoz)
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(transform.localScale.x) * FlipPoz, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
}

public void Flip()
{
    transform.localScale=new Vector3(transform.localScale.x*(-1),transform.localScale.y,transform.localScale.z);
}
```

Comment: Are you using UNet, Photon or something else for your networking?

Comment: Generally everything related to multiplayer works the following way: client wants to flip, or shoot, or jump, etc. so client sends a request to the server, the server determines if that client is allowed to do the action and in case he can the server updates that client and sends the updated information to every client.

Comment: client: hey server, I want to flip;
server: you want to flip? *flips the client*;
server: hey all clients - this guy has flipped!

Comment: I know how it should work in theory.. but I don't know how to code it. It should be very easy to update the flip position to everyone, but I don't know how to do it. I think I am using UNet (for sure I am not using Photon, I tried it before) My code uses code lines for network like this: using UnityEngine.Networking; public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour Network.Destroy(GameObject.Find(name));